# How can I open .py files with python command shell instead of idle?

Tags: python, windows

I feel silly for not being able to figure this out... I used to be able to double-click on a .py file and it would run in command line.  Then, I was cleaning up my hard drive (uninstalled some redundant versions of python), and now I've lost that ability.  I managed to get .py files opening with IDLE, but I liked it better when I could just double click on the .py file and run it.

I've tried to change the default program for .py files to python.exe, but Windows doesn't make the change.  In the 'Open with' window, I browse to python.exe and select it but it doesn't show up as a valid choice.  Why not?

Comment: Solution: reinstall python.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I took your advice and it works now.  I must have screwed something up in my registry?