# Erase lines of code in IDLE shell in order to run .py file in command prompt

Tags: python

I am following a python course on [py4e.org](https://py4e.org) and I have hit a wall in opening/running (do not know the correct term) a .py file in command prompt on a Windows computer. I have tried the solutions at these links thus far [q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37389858/python-run-py-file-works-ok-in-idle-not-via-command-prompt-windows-7-unicod), [q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090097/how-can-i-open-py-files-with-python-command-shell-instead-of-idle), and some others. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076496/i-am-unable-to-run-hello-py-and-get-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax) is what I would like to try next, since I also have `Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.` showing when I open IDLE shell, but I do not know how to delete these words off the script.

Comment: For creating of py-files (Python scripts) you need a text editor (IDLE includes one but also others exist). Copy everything from the shell to the editor and remove problematic parts in the editor. It is not possible to do that in the shell.

Comment: Ok I used a text editor and I was able to open the file in command prompt! However I am receiving a syntax error after it shows what is in the file ```C:\Users\janni> cd py ex2_2.py``` is what I typed to open the file

Comment: "cd" is a command to change the working directory. Maybe you should first learn more about using the command line in general (unfortunately I don't know a good tutorial off the top of my head).